# deployment path issue in css

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I have to rewrite a legacy asp.net mvc app using lots of:

```
Url.Content()
```

to get it to work in a different/additional deployment environment where the virtual directory is a sub directory of the default site.

At the moment css classes like this:

```
.icos-pencil:before { content: url(/content/images/global/icons/usual/icon-pencil.png); }
```

are also broke. Is there a similar 'helper' (?) like `Url.Content` for the css above?

Comment: Why don't you use relative path?

Comment: Can you alter the CSS file?

Comment: @andres - I must be missing something but the above is a relative path. The problem is that this doe not work if the mvc app is running in a sub virtual folder of the default website (e.g. www.bla.com/mvcapp.

Comment: What is the location of the css file that contains the icos-pencil style above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want use helper in js or css file you can write own view engine such as [jsHelper](http://javascripthelper.codeplex.com/) or you can use this code

```
background-image:url('../../content/images/global/icons/usual/icon-pencil.png');
```

becomes

```
background-image:url('content/images/global/icons/usual/icon-pencil.png');
```

Comment: actually, you are right. I have to use ../../../ relative to the css file

Answer (score 0):

Simply use relative path in your CSS.

Comment: As far as I know a path starting with / is absolute.

Comment: fair enough. always thought that only something like this is absolute www.bla.com/folder1/folder2/somecss.css